# Parsing a decimal

Tags: java, parsing, decimal

I have to parse a string formatted like this: "€ 15,10" as a decimal, in order to perform a simple calculation.

The project codebase is completely new to me, however.

I've tried this:

```
String[] strArray = PriceNew.split(" ");
PriceNew = strArray[1];
```

Just to get the numeric part of the string, but that did not work.

I also tried

```
PriceNew = replace(PriceNew, '€ ', '');
```

But that did not work either, because the character encoding is completely off. The euro sign causes the compile to fail.

Comment: Did you try also replacing the coma by a dot after removing the euro symbol?

Comment: Writing Java code in a JSP file the old school way doesn't make it a JSP problem. I removed the irrelevant JSP tag. By the way, why not just store decimals all the time as `BigDecimal` instead of `String`? Use from the beginning on the right data type for the value it represents. It avoids unnecessarily struggling with conversion trouble of all kinds. You can use `NumberFormat` API in Java and `<fmt:formatNumber>` tag in JSP to format it as a currency whenever the value has to be presented to humans.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it real simple,

```
//Remove currency symbol
PriceNew.replace('€', '');
//Remove comma
PriceNew.replace(',', '');
//Remove spaces
PriceNew.trim();
//Cast to new float
float price = new Float(PriceNew);
//Retain decimal value
price /= 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the comma with a decimal point as well:

```
float number = new Float(PriceNew.split(" ")[1].replace(',','.'));
```

- [`String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`<sup>javadoc</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)
- [`Float(String s)`<sup>javadoc</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

For monetary amounts, you might prefer to use BigDecimal instead of float or double to keep the precision:

```
String s = "€ 15,10";
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(s.substring(1).trim().replace(",", "."));
System.out.println(bd); // 15.10
```